# MySQL left join on the same table, double inverted result

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, outer-join

I have this table:

> item | timestamp | value 
>  x | 1 | 30 
>  x | 2 | 40 
>  x | 3 |
>   50 
>  y | 1 | 25 
>  y | 3 | 15

I want to get his result:

> timestamp | xval | yval 
>  1 | 30 | 25 
>  3 | 50 | 15 
>  2 | 40
>   | NULL

But with this query I got a double unwanted result:

```
select x.timestamp, x.value as xval, y.value as yval from test x left join test y on x.timestamp=y.timestamp and x.item!=y.item
```

The result is:

> timestamp | xval | yval 
>  1 | 25 | 30 
>  3 | 15 | 50 
>  1 | 30
>   | 25 
>  3 | 50 | 15 
>  2 | 40 | NULL

I want a result without the first two rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A basic pivot query should work here:

```
SELECT
    timestamp,
    MAX(CASE WHEN item = 'x' THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS xval,
    MAX(CASE WHEN item = 'y' THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS yval
FROM test
GROUP BY
    timestamp
ORDER BY
    timestamp;
```

[image]

### Demo